# How do I get the value of a MSBuild property from a custom task?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, properties

Is there some way to access the value of an MSBuild property from a custom task?

I know I can send them all in, but it would be nice not to :) I am trying to do this from a [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) build.

Or is there some way to access the "build script" currently running? Maybe like an object model and from there get what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
  public override bool Execute()
  {
    string projectFile = BuildEngine.ProjectFileOfTaskNode;

    Engine buildEngine = new Engine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory());

    Project project = new Project(buildEngine);
    project.Load(projectFile);
    foreach(var o in project.EvaluatedProperties)
    {
      // Use properties
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: This helped, but I had to create a new engine. The BuildEngine property only contained an EngineProxy which I was unable to case to an Engine... And when i created a new engine non of the properties vas evaluated. So i just got out $(something). Suggestions? :)

Comment: Unable to cast I ment, not case :)

Comment: This is really helpful, but how would I go about doing this now that MS has deprecated the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project` and `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine` classes? This is the only example that I've found of reading properties from a custom task.